# Error 0x80072736 when deploying app?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am attempting to deploy my Windows Phone 8 app to my HTC 8X from Visual Studio 2012. I get this error:

```
Error   1   Error writing file
'%FOLDERID_SharedData%\PhoneTools\11.0\Install\{12b7fcb7-793b-4023-abeb-14a76d3f7447}\MyApp_Debug_AnyCPU.xap'.
Error 0x80072736: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.
 0      0
```

The app is not currently installed on the device. Restarting Visual Studio and the phone do not fix the problem. If I deploy the app a second time from Visual Studio without restarting it, the error changes to simply:

```
Error   1   0x8974002F      0   0
```

I tried deleting the bin folder and rebuilding the solution. After doing this, the error changes to:

```
Error   1   This operation returned because the timeout period expired.     0   0
```

The phone is developer unlocked, the Windows Phone app is installed and connects to my phone. I have had no prior issues with deployment on my current computer. What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by restarting the computer. Any ideas as to the cause of this issue would still be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and I fixed it by plugging the phone directly into the computer rather than using a USB extension cable.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I changed the USB port & it's worked. (The front USB ports were bugged, but the rear ones were good.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a pending system update on my phone. Installing the update, which restarted the phone, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a sample application. Panorama App. It worked in one room and the deployment error in another.

Error   1   This operation returned because the timeout period expired.
        0   0
Halloween Perhaps! May be I will try restarting the computer. I am using Visual Studio 2013 on a laptop running Windows 10. I had two different apps both Panorama app and they failed to deploy.